# Eigenvector of the A

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have the following matrix $\begin{bmatrix}4 & 2 & 3\\-1 & 1 & -3\\2 &4 &9 \end{bmatrix}$ for which I found $\lambda=8, 3, 3$. Now when I try to row reduce the matrix with $\lambda=3$ I get the following matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & |0\\0 & 0 & 0 & |0\\0 &0 &0 &|0 \end{bmatrix}$. What would be the eigenvector in this case?

Comment: oops! let me correct that.

Comment: yeah I got that from mathematica; I just don't get how I would get that answer from this.

Comment: crystal! thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we really want is to find a basis of the kernel of the transformation, that is, find a basis for the subspace of $\vec x = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2 & x_3}^T$ such that
$$
A\;\vec x = \pmatrix{x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3\\0\\0} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}
$$
Here's one way to do this: set $x_2 = 0$, this reduces to
$$
x_1 +2(0) + 3 x_3 = 0 \implies \vec x = t\pmatrix{-3\\0\\1}
$$
Then, setting $x_3 = 0$, this reduces to
$$
x_1 + 2x_2 + 3(0) = 0 \implies \vec x = s \pmatrix{-2\\1\\0}
$$
We conclude that a vector of the form
$$
\vec x = s \pmatrix{-2\\1\\0} + t \pmatrix{-3\\0\\1}
$$
must be in the kernel of this transformation.  In fact, this accounts for all vectors in the desired null-space.